# Compression problems, zlib?

Tags: c++, compression, zlib

I've been googling for long time already, and I still dont know how to use zlib. Could someone just give exact instructions what I have to do to use it? (MS Visual C++ 2010 on Win7 32). Please not the DLL version.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
In case someone finds this with google, check the comments!

Comment: You said elsewhere it "gives linker errors". Suggest you add them to your question if you want any useful assistance...

Answer (score 2):

The website has [a usage example](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html).

Comment: Well, thats how to use the Code, but I'm having probs with getting the lib somehow. I've tried compiling it but it throws linker errors.

Comment: Create static zlib libraries and add it in project

Comment: A by-the-way-question: does anyone know good examples of gzipping stuff (char* - arrays) with zlib ?

Comment: zlib doesn't do gzip, it does deflate.

Comment: zlib does, really. I've solved my problem some other way, anyway :) Thank you guys.  
Is it possible to accept an answer? I'd like the #2 one :3

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it this will help but my coworker found this the other day when we were looking for a zip library. Looks pretty easy to use (there's an exemple at the end).

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/zlib.html

You still need to have the external library though.